# Let $f:(a,b)\to\Bbb R_{>0}$ be smooth. Can we solve the ODE $\alpha'=f(\alpha)$ such that $\alpha$ has range $(a,b)$?

Tags: analysis

This was an issue that came up when dealing with curve shortening flows – given an immersed smooth plane curve $$\gamma:(a,b)\to\Bbb R^2$$ if we only know that $\lvert\gamma'(u)\rvert\ne0$ for all $u$, then we typically would like to reparametrize $\gamma$ using some smooth arc-length reparametrization, $$\alpha:(0,L)\to(a,b)$$ such that $$\alpha'(u)=\frac{1}{\lvert\gamma'(\alpha(u))\rvert}$$ which gives us the unit-speed reparametrized curved $$\gamma\circ\alpha:(0,L)\to\Bbb R^2.$$

However, an issue that is often glossed over is why $\alpha$ should have full range. Therefore, if we reduce this problem to considering $f:(a,b)\to\Bbb R_{>0}$, I wish to show that there exists a solution to $$\alpha'(u)=f(\alpha(u))$$ with full range. But why is this true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any solution is an increasing function since $f > 0$.  If the upper bound were less than $b$, i.e. $u(t) \to c < b$ as $t \to \infty$, then we'd have $f(u(t)) = u'(t) \to 0$ as $t \to \infty$, but then by continuity of $f$, $f(c) = 0$.
Similarly for the lower bound.